# Invoke a function after the time changes

Tags: javascript

I'm curious if you can invoke a function after the time changes?

For example invoking a function after the minute changes maybe something like this:

```
onMinChange(()=>{console.log('the minute has changed!')})
```

**Note:**

I **do not** mean waiting for a minute to invoke a function like this

```
setInterval(()=>{console.log('the minute has changed!')},60000);
```

there's a difference between

> ✓ *invoking a function after the minute changes* (Current time 2:30:05, invoke function at 2:31:00 )

&

> X *waiting for a minute to invoke a function* (Current time 2:30:05, invoke function at 2:31:05 )

Comment: Just have a running poll set at a shorter interval, and check the cached value of the last known minute. If the value is different, then you know the minute has changed. How "immediate" you want that depends on the interval you choose.

Comment: On browsers or Node.js or...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry I wasn't specific, but both would be good

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built into the web platform that will do this (nor, I think, Node.js's standard library). The closest you can come (without some third-party lib) is to get the time, calculate how long it should be until the next minute, and then use `setTimeout` to schecule a callback. If you want it repeated, repeat as necessary.

Here's an example:

```js
const MINUTE_IN_MS = 60000;
function callNextMinute(fn) {
    const now = Date.now();
    let next = now / MINUTE_IN_MS;
    const ceil = Math.ceil(next);
    if (ceil > next) {
        next = ceil;
    }
    return setTimeout(fn, (next * MINUTE_IN_MS) - now);
}
function tick() {
    console.log(`New minute! Time is ${new Date()}`);
    callNextMinute(tick);
}
console.log(`Started at ${new Date()}`);
callNextMinute(tick);
```

There, the margin of error is ~10 seconds.

Beware that:

1. That kind of recurring execution can have an adverse effect on battery life of mobile devices.
2. Timers are slowed or even stopped for tabs that aren't the active tab in many browsers, so you may well miss the minute if the tab is inactive.

Comment: I thought of something like this but it's still not a definite solution, more of a clever workaround, I was looking for a more inbuilt approach

Comment: @cakelover - Well, as I said, there's nothing in the web platform that does this, so all we have is userland solutions. But note that even if there were something built-in that did this, it would probably have the same issue and limitation I flagged above, for the same reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve behaviour like this with the npm package [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron).

```
var job = new CronJob('* * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every full minute');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: In the browser platform?

Comment: cool and all but can't it be done by vanilla js? besides how does corn work?

Comment: I think it should work in the browser. Though I guess if you are tabbed out, it might skip execution (not sure)

Comment: @cakelover you supply a cron string which determines execution intervals. You can test cron strings here https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Re browsers: it would appear not. On [github](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron), it calls itself "Cron for NodeJS" and relies on `child_process`.